# Change currently running script

Tags: powershell, menu

Is there any way to add text to specific part of script to the currently running script?

If i have a menu with options:

- Install All
- Add item
- Quit

  Could the Add item be possible?

Learning to use powershell (heavy user of batches).

When entering Add item, then a `read-host` would pop up, adding a row between the long row of ### `addwifi -wnm $USERINPUT` afterwards 'restarting' the script.

Current script:

```
#cmd: title Add****
$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Add Wi-Fi networks"
#When Show-Menu –Title 'SetupWi-Fi' is called
function Show-Menu
{
# NOTE if changing warible from somewhere else (Show-Menu -WARIBLE VALUE) then param part must be included
    param (
        [string]$Title = 'SetupWi-Fi'
    )
    Clear-Host
    #cls and echo on @echo off
    Write-Host "================ $Title ================"
    
    Write-Host "a: Add Wi-Fi networks."
    Write-Host "q: Quit."
}
#Do this until x

#For future shortening purposes
function addwifi
{
    param (
        [string]$wnm
        #wnm= wifi name
    )
    netsh wlan add profile filename="$wnm.xml"
    #for some reason (nice for this script) . stops the warible name
}

do
 {
 # call Show-Menu and optionally change varible: –Title 'Warible' changes the $title varible
     Show-Menu
     # makin varible chaase equal user input, placing Selection before it
     $chaase = Read-Host "Selection:"
     #switch according to the varible chaase
     switch ($chaase)
     {
         'a' {
            #'single quote' acts as echo, now executing commands of 'a' varible
             'Adding Wi-Fi networks.'
             $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Adding Wi-Fi networks"
             #note the upper function is called with warible
             #add below here! #####################################################################
             addwifi -wnm laptopidee
             #add above here! #####################################################################
         }
         #close a execution
         #close switch
     }
#close do
 }
#until x: selection == input q
 until ($chaase -eq 'q')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use placeholders that you replace at runtime, though I'm not sure how well it will hold up for more complex scripts.

For example, if you have the following script:

```
$scriptPath = "$PsScriptRoot\$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)"   
$scriptContent = Get-Content "$PsScriptRoot\$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)" -Raw

$newItem = Read-Host "Please enter new command"

##Placeholder

$scriptContent -replace "$([char]0x0023)$([char]0x0023)Placeholder", "$([char]0x0023)$([char]0x0023)Placeholder$([char]0x000D)$([char]0x000A)$newItem" |
    Set-Content -Path $scriptPath
```

Each time you run it, you will be prompted for a new command, which will be added below the `##Placeholder`.  So, if you enter `Get-Process` when prompted, the script would end up on-disk like this:

```
$scriptPath = "$PsScriptRoot\$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)"
$scriptContent = Get-Content "$PsScriptRoot\$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)" -Raw

$newItem = Read-Host "Please enter new command"

##Placeholder
Get-Process

$scriptContent -replace "$([char]0x0023)$([char]0x0023)Placeholder", "$([char]0x0023)$([char]0x0023)Placeholder$([char]0x000D)$([char]0x000A)$newItem" |
    Set-Content -Path $scriptPath
```

Next time you run the script you will be prompted for a new command, which is added to the list, and all commands already on the list will be executed.

Comment: works :) tough I understand, why it shouldn't be used normally (building scripts, for simplicity multiple, but main script asks for admin and allows powershell scripts, remotesigned then opens all setup scripts in order, since I'm selling laptops, it isn't bad to try some out, with 1 script (.cmd) (and it also downloads the others) 1 laptop can be set up.. I don't like swapping SSDs breaking things)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use external files as sources to be pulled in. The Add Item menu option creates another file to be read in at next execution.

Many people did this with batch files using .ini files to hold parameters. Similar construct.

Comment: not clarified myself, but the question was that can you do that, without extra files?

Comment: You can use read-host to get in new information not supplied originally in the script, and it can still be acted upon immediately. However, the new information cannot be written back into the actively running script, as far as I know.